# Can't sort python dictionary which is then output via json to the front end

Tags: javascript, django, json, sorting, django-views

I'm having trouble ordering an ajax json result which is then applied to a drop down box in my django application. I'll first step through what I'm doing and where it is I'm going wrong.

1.**I Make an Ajax Call**

This Ajax call takes a car model, and returns via json a list of all variants for that model of car:

```
$('select[name=carMod]').change(function(){
    model = $("#carMod option:selected").val();
    request_url = '/ajax/modelBadgeSearch/' + model + '/';
    $.ajax({
        url: request_url,
        success: function(data){
            $('select[name=carBad]').empty();
            $('select[name=carBad]').append('<option selected="true" value="None">Variant</option>');
            $.each(data['results'], function(key, value){
                $('select[name=carBad]').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value +'</option>');
            });
        }

    })
    return false;
})
```

**2. Via my request URL above it hits my view**

Everything is ordered as it should be in "latest_bad_list", but as soon as turn it into key value pairs in my "vehicle_code_list" dictionary it seems to lose all ordering (verified).

```
def get_vehicle_code (request, model1):

    vID = vehicleModel.objects.get(slug=model1)
    latest_bad_list = vehicleCode.objects.filter(vehicleModel = vID.id).order_by('variantCode').distinct('variantCode')
    vehicle_code_list = {}
    for vM in latest_bad_list:
        vehicle_code_list[vM.slug] = vM.variantCode

    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'results': vehicle_code_list}), mimetype="application/json")
```

**3. What I've tried**

Currently my output is as follows which is successfully cut up by my JS function, just in the wrong order:

```
{"results": {"evo-ix": "Evo IX", "evo-vi": "Evo VI", "vrx": "VRX", "evo-iii": "Evo III", "evo-vii": "Evo VII", "evo-iv": "Evo IV", "evo-i": "Evo I", "evo-v": "Evo V", "evo-ii": "Evo II", "evo-viii": "Evo VIII", "evo-x": "Evo X"}}
```

I've tried using the sorted function in the following manner:

```
sorted(vehicle_code_list.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```

Which then orders everything correctly but it is returned in a different format which my JS can't handle as follows:

```
{"results": [["evo-i", "Evo I"], ["evo-ii", "Evo II"], ["evo-iii", "Evo III"], ["evo-iv", "Evo IV"], ["evo-ix", "Evo IX"], ["evo-v", "Evo V"], ["evo-vi", "Evo VI"], ["evo-vii", "Evo VII"], ["evo-viii", "Evo VIII"], ["evo-x", "Evo X"], ["vrx", "VRX"]]}
```

I'm relatively new to the whole web development thing so apologies if this is a rookie question or I don't understand everything fully yet but any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the return statement to the following:

```
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'results': vehicle_code_list}, sort_keys=True), mimetype="application/json")
```

Thought I had tried that already and no luck but this seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

The **sorted** method returns a list type.  You can recast the list that is returned from the **sorted** method back to a dictionary using the following code.

**List to dictionary code**

```
dict(sorted(vehicle_code_list.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(0)))
```

Comment: You can do that, but there is absolutely no point since dictionaries are unsorted so the order will be lost.

Comment: I just tried this and you're right, it does revert back to unordered, I did find something which I thought I had already tried, please see my answer below

Comment: Cool.  Sounds like you solved your own problem then...  If you were using Python3 (appears you are not), you could investigate the [Ordered Dictionary](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=collections.ordereddict#collections.OrderedDict) as another alternative.